# How can i get the blob type of the uploaded file?

Tags: codenameone

I trying to upload a picture from my mobile app for which i am using codenameone multipart request every thing is coming fine to my webservice method call but while i trying to convert coming string filepath to File type its showing me FileNotFound Exception (note: as i am uploading my file from a mobile device and not from my local machine its working fine in my local machine because it getting the path here).I need the File type so that i can convert it into FileInputStream to store the BLOB type in my database.

So, can you please give a hint to resolve my issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

See [this sample](https://github.com/codenameone/codenameone-demos/blob/master/PhotoShare/PhotosServer/src/java/com/codename1/apps/photoshare/UploadServlet.java) of an image upload servlet that accepts an image from the client. This is discussed in depth in [this course on Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/build-mobile-ios-apps-in-java-using-codename-one/).

As you can see the path is something that's useful for your reference not for reading the file. You need to get the blob data of the file and use that to read the uploaded file.